# LaTeX Beamer Theme Amsterdam

Tags: beamer, themes

I have a little problem when I want to use the theme Amsterdam download in this [page](https://latex.simon04.net/)

And when I want to compile I have my pdf but I have some tex Error like that :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \abbreviations
l.3 \disallowuchyph
l.4 \overfullhboxmark
l.7 \tabbingaccents
l.8 \automaticlettrine
```

If I understand well, all those commands are in the file  french.cfg. But I don't understand why I can not just put the beamer theme.

I precise that I am on Windows (with MikteX).

Thanks a lot,

Comment: With [this MWE](http://pastebin.com/tuswsvhH) and the [Amsterdam theme](https://latex.simon04.net/beamerthemeAmsterdam.sty) in my local folder, I am unable to replicate your problem (under TeX Live).

Comment: I check with your code and I can compile also.

Comment: @G.Sophys Good to hear that the linked code compiles for you. Next step: Please put together such a small sample document, that reproduces your error.

Comment: To me I have this [code](http://pastebin.com/Pt9as1Ns). In French and old but I can check without section. And which part give the error. We can take this and remove pictures etc ...

Comment: @G.Sophys: I replaced all your images to ones from the [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) - `example-image`, `example-image-a` and `example-image-b`, and was able to compile it without problem.

Comment: Ok this is my \usepackage[french]{babel} who make the error, I don't know why .. maybe my package is not good install ?

Comment: At the end, this is just one story about my installation because I unistall and reinstall my MikteX 2.9 and this works !!!